# Good problem books on martingales

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, book-recommendation, martingales

I am looking for a book with good collection of exercises in Martingale theory. So far I know Durrett and Billingsley, but I am looking for an even better collection of problems. Particularly on Optional Stopping theorem, Backward martingales, martingale convergence theorems, exchangeability, etc.

Comment: It depends on graduation level, you should mention your graduation too.

Comment: Master in Mathematics

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at *Probability with Martingales* by David Williams.